# How do I make Anaconda my default terminal in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, anaconda

In Visual Studio Code, when I click on
Terminal > new terminal
it opens Powershell.

[image]

But I want instead it to open Anaconda.
How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your python from with the PowerShell terminal simply by specify your your conda virtual environment as the interpreter like so:

Open VS code.
Type ctrl+shift+P to open the command palette.

Enter "python:select interpreter" into the command pallet

You should see your conda environments,  select the conda environment you created before and want to use

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In VSCode press `<F1>` and search for

```
Terminal: Select Default Shell
```

and then pick `Command Prompt` from the dropdown list.

Besides this you need to

```
Python: Select Interpreter
```

and pick any of your conda environments. After that whenever you open an integrated terminal, VScode will run the cmd shell and activate conda. This is equivalent to running the "**Anaconda Prompt**".

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

In VSCode press `<F1>` or `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`P` and search for

```
Python: Select Interpreter
```

and pick any of conda environments (with python installed) which you have already created (you can do it by running `conda create -n my_virtualenv_name python` on the Anaconda command line).

After that, whenever you open a new integrated terminal (`CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ò`), VScode will run the cmd shell and activate conda.
This is equivalent to running the "**Anaconda Prompt**".

Comment: credits to @peter and thimotyG., whose answers I upvoted.